# Shorten nmcli connection timeout from 120s to 10s, try a lower priority interface quicker

Tags: 16.04, network-manager, dhcp, headless, avahi

On Ubuntu 16.04 lts I am using nmcli to manage the network interfaces. I have connections like so.

```
NAME          UUID                                  TYPE             DEVICE
link-local-0  da55e0dd-c5a2-414c-9ec5-f17b781df1a4  802-3-ethernet   eth0
ethernet-0    395f7a42-fe6c-4863-8527-1d94d9946da9  802-3-ethernet   --
```

When the device boots up and it is directly connect to another computer via Ethernet it takes around 120 seconds before ethernet-0 will timeout and move on to the link-local-0 connection. My goal is to have the device be reachable immediately via the peer to peer connection if it is not plugged in to the network. I tried changing the ipv4.dhcp-timeout value between 15 and 2 but it did not seem to make any difference, I have not been able to find where the timeout is configured to make the first connection fail faster.

nmcli tool, version 1.2.6 . The device is headless. Ubuntu 16.06. The avahi zero conf daemon is also running.

1. How can I have the device configure its self with a 169.254.0.0/16 address when dhcp is not available within 0-5 seconds of initial boot up while still using network-manager.
2. Network manager supports dispatcher scripts, would making a dispatcher script be the correct way to solve this?
3. Am I just going about this the wrong way?

Here is the configurations of each interface

```
nmcli> print
===============================================================================
                    Connection profile details (ethernet-0)
===============================================================================
connection.id:                          ethernet-0
connection.uuid:                        395f7a42-fe6c-4863-8527-1d94d9946da9
connection.interface-name:              eth0
connection.type:                        802-3-ethernet
connection.autoconnect:                 yes
connection.autoconnect-priority:        2
connection.timestamp:                   1543331562
connection.read-only:                   no
connection.permissions:
connection.zone:                        --
connection.master:                      --
connection.slave-type:                  --
connection.autoconnect-slaves:          -1 (default)
connection.secondaries:
connection.gateway-ping-timeout:        0
connection.metered:                     unknown
connection.lldp:                        -1 (default)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
802-3-ethernet.port:                    --
802-3-ethernet.speed:                   0
802-3-ethernet.duplex:                  --
802-3-ethernet.auto-negotiate:          yes
802-3-ethernet.mac-address:             --
802-3-ethernet.cloned-mac-address:      --
802-3-ethernet.mac-address-blacklist:
802-3-ethernet.mtu:                     auto
802-3-ethernet.s390-subchannels:
802-3-ethernet.s390-nettype:            --
802-3-ethernet.s390-options:
802-3-ethernet.wake-on-lan:             1 (default)
802-3-ethernet.wake-on-lan-password:    --
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ipv4.method:                            auto
ipv4.dns:
ipv4.dns-search:
ipv4.dns-options:                       (default)
ipv4.dns-priority:                      0
ipv4.addresses:
ipv4.gateway:                           --
ipv4.routes:
ipv4.route-metric:                      -1
ipv4.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv4.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv4.dhcp-client-id:                    --
ipv4.dhcp-timeout:                      2
ipv4.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv4.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv4.dhcp-fqdn:                         --
ipv4.never-default:                     no
ipv4.may-fail:                          yes
ipv4.dad-timeout:                       -1 (default)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ipv6.method:                            auto
ipv6.dns:
ipv6.dns-search:
ipv6.dns-options:                       (default)
ipv6.dns-priority:                      0
ipv6.addresses:
ipv6.gateway:                           --
ipv6.routes:
ipv6.route-metric:                      -1
ipv6.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv6.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv6.never-default:                     no
ipv6.may-fail:                          yes
ipv6.ip6-privacy:                       -1 (unknown)
ipv6.addr-gen-mode:                     stable-privacy
ipv6.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv6.dhcp-hostname:                     --
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

## Link local

```
                   Connection profile details (link-local-0)
===============================================================================
connection.id:                          link-local-0
connection.uuid:                        da55e0dd-c5a2-414c-9ec5-f17b781df1a4
connection.interface-name:              eth0
connection.type:                        802-3-ethernet
connection.autoconnect:                 yes
connection.autoconnect-priority:        1
connection.timestamp:                   1543420131
connection.read-only:                   no
connection.permissions:
connection.zone:                        --
connection.master:                      --
connection.slave-type:                  --
connection.autoconnect-slaves:          -1 (default)
connection.secondaries:
connection.gateway-ping-timeout:        0
connection.metered:                     unknown
connection.lldp:                        -1 (default)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
802-3-ethernet.port:                    --
802-3-ethernet.speed:                   0
802-3-ethernet.duplex:                  --
802-3-ethernet.auto-negotiate:          yes
802-3-ethernet.mac-address:             --
802-3-ethernet.cloned-mac-address:      --
802-3-ethernet.mac-address-blacklist:
802-3-ethernet.mtu:                     auto
802-3-ethernet.s390-subchannels:
802-3-ethernet.s390-nettype:            --
802-3-ethernet.s390-options:
802-3-ethernet.wake-on-lan:             1 (default)
802-3-ethernet.wake-on-lan-password:    --
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ipv4.method:                            link-local
ipv4.dns:
ipv4.dns-search:
ipv4.dns-options:                       (default)
ipv4.dns-priority:                      0
ipv4.addresses:
ipv4.gateway:                           --
ipv4.routes:
ipv4.route-metric:                      -1
ipv4.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv4.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv4.dhcp-client-id:                    --
ipv4.dhcp-timeout:                      0
ipv4.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv4.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv4.dhcp-fqdn:                         --
ipv4.never-default:                     no
ipv4.may-fail:                          yes
ipv4.dad-timeout:                       -1 (default)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ipv6.method:                            auto
ipv6.dns:
ipv6.dns-search:
ipv6.dns-options:                       (default)
ipv6.dns-priority:                      0
ipv6.addresses:
ipv6.gateway:                           --
ipv6.routes:
ipv6.route-metric:                      -1
ipv6.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv6.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv6.never-default:                     no
ipv6.may-fail:                          yes
ipv6.ip6-privacy:                       -1 (unknown)
ipv6.addr-gen-mode:                     stable-privacy
ipv6.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv6.dhcp-hostname:                     --
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The route table

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlan0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     100    0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlan0
224.0.0.0       *               240.0.0.0       U     100    0        0 eth0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer on this page. https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/configuring_the_dhcp_client_behavior

I needed to set `ipv4.may-fail` to no. Then it will just time out (`ipv4.dhcp-timeout`) after 2 seconds. Retrying the connection 4 times and then failing. This way I only wait for 8 seconds vs two mins or so.

Comment: Lol, use an actual library.for managing network interfaces

Comment: I know it was long ago, but did this work? I tried the same thing and it still takes 2 minutes to switch profile...

Comment: It was a long time ago, I can't really remember.

Comment: @JackLilhammers, I had the same problem, and I think I found the solution.  See https://askubuntu.com/a/1432588/657351

Comment: @grahas Thank you anyway!

Comment: @JimFischer I ended up doing the same thing, thank you! Also after reading  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/598407 I'll test if it's still an issue in 22.04